# git Commit Error displaying some change in the pre-commit file

Tags: git

At the time of commit, following Git error appears:

```
.git/hooks/pre-commit: line 2: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_65\bin/bin/java: No such file or directory
git did not exit cleanly (exit code 1)
```

How to resolve it, as I'm new to Git, so don't know much of it.

Comment: This has little to do with git. It can't find java because it's either not installed, or the path is incorrect (`\bin/bin/java` looks weird)

Comment: I have Java installed on my machine, which path do I need to put here, can you help me with this.

Comment: How am I supposed to know that? It's just the path to where you installed java

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has nothing to do with GIT. The pre-commit hook script refers to this path to find java which is incorrectly mentioned. Rather than having the full path here in the hook, add the java executable to the path in your environment so that you can call it by just using "java" which would be easier to manage.